# How to replace a string globally in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, str-replace

I want make a function in AngularJS  to replace all values on a page but I am getting an error.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="number_only(num_page)" ng-model="num_page"/>
<input type="text" ng-keyup="number_only(num_book)" ng-model="num_book"/>
<input type="text" ng-keyup="number_only(price)" ng-model="price"/>
```

and here is my script:

```
$scope.number_only= function(num_page){
    return $scope.num_page = num_page.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: every time you are updating the only num_page?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a generic method which you can use from any where in the program right ? Then create this function inside your main controller ( The controller which is associated with index.html) and then you can simply call it from anywhere

Comment: @RahulSharma no, I need update all, it my problem

Answer (score 1):

In your code the num_page always updates irrespective of the model.

You can assign the value of model to ng-keyup directly to work as expected.

Here is the working example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.num_page = null;
    $scope.num_book = null;
    $scope.price = null;
    
    $scope.number_only= function(num_page){
    return num_page.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

Number of Page<input type="text" ng-keyup="num_page=number_only(num_page)" ng-model="num_page"/><br>
Number Of Book<input type="text" ng-keyup="num_book=number_only(num_book)" ng-model="num_book"/><br>
Price<input type="text" ng-keyup="price=number_only(price)" ng-model="price"/>
<br>
Number of Page: {{num_page}}
Number of Book: {{num_book}}
Price: {{price}}
</div>



</body>
</html>
```